# Largescale sparse matrix inversion and using it in ARPACK OP

Tags: c++, matlab, arpack

I'm trying rewrite matlab eigs function as C++ wrapper of ARPACK because arpack++ (C++ wrapper for arpack) is very slow in regular mode, shift-invert mode doesn't work properly. But I'm in stuck and I need a kick. :)

```
LU Factorization
```

Matlab function:

```
function [L,U,pp,qq,dgAsB] = LUfactor
    AsB = A;
    [L,U,pp,qq,dgAsB] = lu(AsB);
end
```

Is it any library for c++ which return me output like code above? And I'd like ask what does mean qq and dgAsB. Meaning L and U is clear and pp too, I learned it at uni but I don't know what is meaning others.

Arpack OP

```
function [v] = AminusSigmaBsolve (u)

     v = qq*(U \ (L \ (pp*(dgAsB \ u))));

end
```

Arpack OP for shift invert mode is defined (A - sigma*I )^-1*I*u. First I can't understand how matlab code is related to Arpack OP. And I'd like to ask if exists any library for C++ with which I can write efficiency code of AminusSigmaBsolve in C++.

Thank you for your answers because I'd like to use program as efficient as Matlab in C++.

Comment: I'm confused. Do you want to do eigen solving, or LU decomposition.

Comment: I also am sceptical of your claims that arpack++ does not work. Respectfully I think it more likely that it works fine but that you are perhaps misusing it one way or another.

Comment: Both. LU decomposition is tool for compute inverse matrix in Arpack OP.

Comment: Do you really want to compute the inverse? Usually that's something that should not be done. Usually you use LU to solve Ax=b for the unknown x. And LU and eigen solve are different. If you want to do LU, which library do you want to use?

Comment: As for the return values of `LUFactor`, the docs explain them: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/lu.html

Comment: Ok, fine.

Arpack works in few modes regular it solve clasical problem A*x = lambda*x and shift-invert (A - sigma*I)^-1*x = lamdba*x. Mode which matlab use for solving smallest eigenvalues of spectra is shift-invert small-eigenvalues became largest a it very quick converge. LU decomposition is used for inversion.

Next I'm using arpack++ right now but solving is very slowly for matrixes about 14000x14000. I computation k smallest eigenvalues.

Comment: arpack++ just has plain old ARPACK underneath. So clearly you are asking a different problem in your code when compared to your MATLAB code. But arpack++ does work. Don't give up on it. The LU factorization will need to be done by something other than ARPACK. I think MATLAB uses UMFPACK for sparse LU. If your product is commercial then you'll want to look for something other than UMFPACK . Or pay up!

Comment: My arpack++ code is:

ARluSymMatrix<T> matrix( this->L->rows, this->L->m->nnz(),  matrix2csr.vals, matrix2csr.colIndx, matrix2csr.rowIndx );

ARluSymStdEig<T> problem( 120, matrix, "SM" );
problem.SetRegularMode();
problem.ChangeMaxit( iter );

But in matlab solving takes about 10s and in c++ takes about 15minutes.

Comment: No my product is not commercial it is my thesis but my suvervisor can't give me any advice so I trying it on internet and I little bit confused too.

Comment: Problem must be in your code. Surely. Presumably arpack++ comes with examples. Anyway, I don't think this can be done in comments. Your question asks for alternatives to arpack++ but I think that's a mistake.

Comment: Ok. I'll be very happy that I haven't to write new software and I can use Arpack++. So your advice is use umfpack arpack++ function instead SuperLU?

Comment: No. SuperLU is good. Arpack++ is good. UMFPACK is good. You've picked SuperLU for the LU part, and arpack++ for the eigen solve. Both fine libraries. Stick with them, and debug your code. Don't give up on the libraries and hope that picking different libraries will solve the problem. The problem is in your code and you just need to stay with it and debug it. That's my opinion.

Comment: Hello David,

I'm trying your advice. Example arpack++ shift-invert works fine in example using for factorization SuperLU. Maybe I make mistake in definition of matrix, so I try rewrite CSC format by myself and debug it now I use boost matrix for creating sparse row format, but in regular mode it works fine but very slowly. 

Next I tried compile example shift-invert example with use UMFPACK for factorization and I got this error. 

http://pastebin.com/7YFyJ5R3

undefined reference to `umd21i_'

Comment: Replacing SuperLU with UMFPACK won't help. I can't debug this in comments. Sorry.

Comment: UMFPACK worked perfectly for me for sparse LU integrated in a commercial C++ project, you need to provide BLAS and check the licenses (version <= 5.1 is LGPL).